# Subtracting from mmm-YY fn:current-dateTimedate in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have current `xslt xp20:format-dateTime(string(fn:current-dateTime ()), "[Mn,*-3]-[Y01]")` to retrieve current month in mmm-yy format but I am not able to subtract a month. I would imagine it would look something along the lines of `xp20:format-dateTime(string(fn:current-dateTime ()), "[Mn,*-3]-[Y01]") - xsd:dayTimeDuration('P1M')), '[Mn,*-3]-[Y01]')`

Comment: Which XSLT processor is this for?

Comment: I am using Oracle Integration Cloud Service so I am not sure which XSLT processing they use.

Comment: It seems to be an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports some extension functions from the XSLT 2.0 set. You can verify this as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153). If you cannot make the XSLT 2.0 solution below work, I'll add another that uses only XSLT 1.0 (provided you have a way to get the current date, which apparently you do).

Comment: Note also that if you don't have a way to subtract a yearMonthDuration, you can extract the day and use it to subtract a dayTimeDuration with the same value. This will return the last day of the previous month - and you can format it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 or higher you can subtract one month from the current date using:

```
current-date() - xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M')
```

then format the resulting date the way you want it.

For example, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date() - xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M'), '[Mn,*-3]-[Y01]')" />
```

will return:

```
dec-22
```

if performed on any day of January 2023.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Integration Cloud the below returned previous month and year in Mmm-YY.

```
`xp20:format-dateTime(string(xsd:dateTime(fn:current-dateTime()-xsd:yearMonthDuration('P1M'))),"[Mn,*-3]-[Y01]")`
```

Ran in Jan 2023 returned Dec-22